# Cannot move selected combination of resources. The resource: 'XXX' is missing from the move request.

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-resource-group

I have a resource group that looks like this:

[image]

App Service Plan `UispWestEuServerFarm` contains only single app: `evisserver`.

When I try to move evisserver together with UispWestEuServerFarm to another resource group I get an error:

> Cannot move selected combination of resources. The resource:
>   '/blabla/resourceGroups/vyvojari.sk/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/vyvojari-sk-dev'
>   is missing from the move request. Please select all the resources in
>   the source subscription and resource group so that they can be moved
>   together. (Code: BadRequest, Target: Microsoft.Web/serverFarms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s only a certain type of combinations that would support an App Service resource move. You need to move just the app first (evisserver) and once that succeeds you can move its app service plan (UispWestEuServerFarm). Refer [Move Resources: App Service Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#app-service-limitations) for details.